# How to show only the TabView in a SilverAppBar

Tags: flutter, tabbar, tabview, nestedscrollview, flutter-appbar

I'd basically like to have a TabView navigation in the middle of my page.
To do so I used a SliverAppBar inside a NestedScrollView. 
My SliverAppBar is only composed by my TabView, I wrapped my TabView inside a SliverAppBar in order to used the pinned: true propriety.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: NestedScrollView(

        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
              height: 500,
              color: Colors.red,
            )),

          SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    text: "Home",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Example page",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                  )
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              )),

          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageExample(),
            PageExample(),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

It does the trick, my problem is I'd like to hide/remove this SliverAppBar that wrapped my TabBar:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set expandedHeight to 0:

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: NestedScrollView(

```
    headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
      return <Widget>[
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.red,
        )),

      SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 0,
          pinned: true,
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: "Home",
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Example page",
                icon: Icon(Icons.help),
              )
            ],
            controller: _tabController,
          )),

      ];
    },
    body: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageExample(),
        PageExample(),
      ],
      controller: _tabController,
    ),
  ),
);
```